# Is there a way to cancel ALL scheduled messages in azure service bus topic without knowing their sequence numbers?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Use case:

1. We use a azure service bus topic.
2. Based on a business rule, we sometimes schedule a message to be delivered to a topic at a future time.
3. In case of system mis-configuration, we have a need to cancel all scheduled messages to a particular topic.
4. We do not have sequence number for each of the scheduled message.

What I found so far:

- According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2016/07/11/cross-post-canceling-scheduled-messages/, I can cancel a particular scheduled message if I have a sequence number for that scheduled message.
- I did not find any other API related to this topic. May be I do not know where to look for this information.

Question:

1. Is it possible to delete ALL scheduled messages to a particular topic without knowing any of their sequence numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is "no".

When you schedule messages and know you would need to cancel some of those, you should hold on to the `SequenceNumber`s returned back when scheduling using `client.CancelScheduledMessageAsync(sequenceNumber)`. I've blogged about this option [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus--canceling-scheduled-messages). I. Your case, you'd need a [`TopicClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.topicclient.schedulemessageasync?view=azure-dotnet) to schedule messages.