# Azure Service Bus - Cancel or reschedule scheduled message without Sequence number

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I've got an entity, lets say a document which gets frequently updated by a user (aka live-save). Once there's a delay of 5 min in updates which might indicate that user most likely stopped editing document, one needs to perform some non-critical but time consuming job for that document. Let's say a preview generation and caclulate some statistics. In other words I need some sort of debounce mechanism.

My idea is to send a scheduled message after each update on ASB queue to deliver it in 5 min and cancel previous one. I can pass the document guid as MessageId to identify previous message. However, I cannot find a way to cancel previous message since the API requires to pass a Sequence ID received from previous scheduling and I don't want to store it in the DB since it would have to abandon the idea of stateless service and the presence of the DB actually makes ASB redundant.

So far, I'm planning to use scheduling along with deduplication. It almost solves my problem  but it does not exactly what I want. It has behavior of throttling (1st message is picked up and then further messages with same MessageId are ignored for certain period of time) whereas I need debouncing.

There's also an option of [full scan of queue with Peek](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/azure-service-bus-peek-delete-scheduled-message-which-has-future/ba-p/1648243) method but it looks like it's not recommended approach in production.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you [Sean Feldman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59563/sean-feldman). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

No, you can't cancel or reschedule scheduled message without knowing a sequence number.

> When you schedule messages and know you would need to cancel some of those, you should hold on to the `SequenceNumber` returned back when scheduling using `client.CancelScheduledMessageAsync(sequenceNumber)`.

You can refer to [Is there a way to cancel ALL scheduled messages in azure service bus topic without knowing their sequence numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52358059/15969115), [Azure Service Bus - Canceling Scheduled Messages](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus--canceling-scheduled-messages) and [Azure Service Bus Essentials — Scheduled Messages](https://medium.com/event-driven-utopia/azure-service-bus-essentials-scheduled-messages-98fd542f9d55)

Comment: That's a bummer. It complicates life a lot without any apparent technical reason since ASB already has deduplication mechanism via MessageId.